# Understanding CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE limit OpenCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, opencl, gpgpu

I have little bit difficulty understanding max work group limit reported by OpenCL and how it affects the program.

So my program is reporting following thing,

```
   CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES  : 1024, 1024, 1024
   CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE  : 256
   CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS : 3
```

Now I am writing program to add vectors with 1 million entries.
So the calculation for globalSize and localSize for NDRange is as follows

```
   int localSize = 64;
   // Number of total work items - localSize must be devisor
   globalSize = ceil(n/(float)localSize)*localSize;

 .......

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of the data set 
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalSize, &localSize,
                                                              0, NULL, NULL);
```

Here as per my understanding OpenCL indirectly calculates the number of work groups it will launch.
For above example

```
globalSize = 15625 * 64 -> 1,000,000 -> So this is total number of threads that will be launched 
localSize = 64 -> So each work group will have 64 work items
```

Hence from above we get

```
Total Work Groups Launched = globalSize/ localSize -> 15625 Work Groups
```

Here my confusion starts,
If you see value reported by OpenCL CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE  : 256 So, I was thinking this means max my device can launch 256 work groups in one dimension,

but above calculations showed that I am launching 15625 work groups.

So how is this thing working ?

I hope some one can clarify my confusion.
I am sure I am understanding something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification of `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html,
`CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` indicate the limits of local size (`CL_​KERNEL_​WORK_​GROUP_​SIZE` is `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` in OpenCL 1.2).

```
const int dimension = n;
const int localSizeDim[n] = { ... }; // Each element must be less than or equal to 'CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES[i]'
const int localSize = localSizeDim[0] * localSizeDim[1] * ... * localSizeDim[n-1]; // The size must be less than or equal to 'CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZ'
```

I couldn't find the device limit of global work items, but maximum value representable by `size t` is the limit of global work items in the description of the error `CL_​INVALID_​GLOBAL_​WORK_​SIZE`.

Comment: So looks like there is no limit on number of total work groups. But the number of total work items is 65535 (limit of size_t) and those constants basically telling the local size i.e number of work items per work group which is 256. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni: 65535 is not the limit of `size_t`.